# How to embed complete Flickr gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flickr

Is there any way I can use flickr photos to make a photo gallery for my site? I want to fetch flickr photos so that I can directly update my gallery by uploading photos on flickr.
I also checked for flickr API but flickr doesn't allow to do so.Please provide me some solution.

Comment: _" I also checked for flickr API but flickr doesn't allow to do so"_,  are you sure about that: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/ , https://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html , https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.galleries.getPhotos.html

Comment: I think you misunderstood.With flickr API I can put one frame on my site and then I can navigate the set using arrows but if I want to show actual gallery that's I didn't find anywhere but at some places it shows that it is prohibited

Comment: I think you are talking about the embed code, that is not API. http://jsfiddle.net/SJe22/ this fiddle shows the use of the flickr api to retrieve photos from a test account i made.